# Rails @import compass not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

Here's my application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/

@import "compass/reset";
```

Getting a 404 on the compass reset:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/compass/reset 404 (Not Found)
```

BTW, running Rails 3.2.3. Thanks!

Comment: have you included the compass gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: i have never had much luck with adding things to the manifest file itself. have you tried moving the @import statement to a different file in the tree?

Comment: i haven't tried moving it around, but i will. the thing i don't get is, where are the actual compass files? if i knew where they were i'd probably better be able to include them in my project i'd think.

Comment: the actual files are in the compass-rails gem.  which brings up the point that you also need the 'compass-rails' gem, not only the 'compass' gem.

Comment: adding 'compass-rails' didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Rename `application.css` to `application.css.scss`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the web server.

Comment: It's also a good idea to remove the sprockets `require` directives (i.e remove all the `*= require something` in the `application.css` file.

Comment: @richsinn how replace it? for exemple importe jqueryui ?